# Prove an initial value problem blows up in finite time.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Given the initial value problem $$y'(t)=p(t)+y^2(t)$$ $$y(0)=\frac{1}{2}$$ for $t>0$
where $p(t)$ is a continuous function such that  $p(t)>0$.

Prove the initial value problem blows up in finite time.

My attempt, $$y'\geq p(t)$$
So $$y(t) \geq \int_0^t p(s)ds$$
For some $t_0$ I get  $$y(t_0) \geq \int_0^{t_0} p(s)ds$$
Now I have $$\frac{y'}{y^2} \geq 1$$ and by integrating both sides from $t_0$ to $t$ I get $$y(t)\geq \frac{1}{\frac{1}{y_0}-t+t_0}$$
So since the lower bound blows up for $$t=t_0+\frac{1}{y(t_0)}$$ so does $y$.

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Why is $y'/y \ge 1$?

Comment: Now that the second half is correct, you need to clarify what you want to achieve with the first half. Possibly you just want to ensure that $y$ stays positive? Why not include the initial value, $y(t)\ge y_0+\int_0^tp(s)ds$?

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is not correct as the inequality $\frac{y^\prime}{y}\ge 1$ is not correct.

Let’s consider a solution at the right of $0$. As $p$ is supposed to be positive, $y(t)$ is increasing and we have

$$0\le \frac{y^\prime(t)}{p(t)+y^2(t)}=1\le  \frac{y^\prime(t)}{y^2(t)} $$ integrating the inequalities on $[0,t]$ we get

$$0 \le t \le 2-\frac{1}{y(t)}\le 2 $$ as $y(t) \ge y(0)=\frac{1}{2}$.

**A solution can’t exist beyond $t=2$.**

Comment: I mistakenly wrote $\frac{y'}{y} \geq 1$ instead of $\frac{y'}{y^2} \geq 1$, the bound that I got came by solving $\frac{y'}{y^2}\geq 1$